# TurtleBot plays songs?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any ROS package that can play songs in iRobot Create of Turtlebot?

Thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60861/turtlebot-plays-songs?/) by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2013-04-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, the create_node has a bonus mode you should checkout.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Also, you can give sound files (.wav, .ogg) to [sound_play](http://www.ros.org/wiki/sound_play) (this isn't limited to `Turtlebot`).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-06-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) on 2013-06-25**:
Thank you very much. sound_play and speech synthesis system is exactly what I want.